Nested Conditional Statements with 'fp' Package Problem
I've been struggling with getting a nested conditional structure using the \FPiflt and \FPifgt commands from the 'fp' (floating point) package to determine if a numeric value is within a range specified by the specified values of \minvalue and \maxvalue.
The provided code works for values within and greater than the range, but returns 'too may }', 'extra \else' and 'extra \fi' errors.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}


\def\minvalue{5.0}
\def\maxvalue{10.0}
% Uncomment one of these to test different scenarios
 \def\currentline{2.6}
% \def\currentline{7.3}
%\def\currentline{17.3}

minvalue = \minvalue \par
maxvalue = \maxvalue \par
currentline = \currentline \par

% First condition: if currentline > minvalue
\FPifgt{\currentline}{\minvalue}
{Inner Loop:\par \currentline{} is greater than \texttt{minvalue} \par%
%   % Second condition nested within the first: if currentline < maxvalue
    \FPiflt{\currentline}{\maxvalue}
    {\currentline{} Less than \texttt{maxvalue} \par In Range \minvalue{} to \maxvalue \par}
    \else
    {\currentline{} is greater than \texttt{maxvalue} \par Out of range \par}
    \fi
}
\else
{Less than \texttt{minvalue} \par \currentline{} Out of range \minvalue{} to \maxvalue \par}
\fi
    
\end{document}



You can't nest the elements, as the first occurrence of \else is used to complete the syntax of the conditional. Instead, use a more basic implementation and some help from xfp (don't need to include it in a recent LaTeX distribution).

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\def\minvalue{5.0}
\def\maxvalue{10.0}
% Uncomment one of these to test different scenarios
 \def\currentline{2.6}
% \def\currentline{7.3}
% \def\currentline{17.3}

minvalue = \minvalue \par
maxvalue = \maxvalue \par
currentline = \currentline \par

\ifnum\fpeval{\currentline > \minvalue} = 1
  Inner Loop:\par \currentline{} is greater than \texttt{minvalue} \par%
  \ifnum\fpeval{\currentline < \maxvalue} = 1
    \currentline{} Less than \texttt{maxvalue} \par In Range \minvalue{} to \maxvalue \par
  \else
    \currentline{} is greater than \texttt{maxvalue} \par Out of range \par
  \fi
\else
  Less than \texttt{minvalue} \par \currentline{} Out of range \minvalue{} to \maxvalue \par
\fi

\end{document}

You'll have to update your logic if you want to include the limits of the range.
